# InertiaJS - validate multi step form - with Interia or Axios?

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I use InertiaJS and Laravel for a web application and I have created a Multi Step Form. For the Form I have used the Inertia helper `useForm`. Now, when clicking the button to go to the next step, I want to send a validation request of the form to a validation controller. I ask myself how I can achieve this.

First, I thought I can do something like this:

```
form
    .transform((data) => ({
        ...data,
        step : activeStepIndex.value,
    }))
    .post(route('setup.validate'), {
    preserveState: true,
    preserveScroll: true,
});
```

This seems to send a request, but the endpoint is sending a 302 response and according to the docs, as far as I understand it, I need to do a redirect - https://inertiajs.com/redirects / https://inertiajs.com/forms#submitting-forms

Then I thought, that I can use a classic axios call. Here I have the issue, that I submit the whole form to the validation form request, and therefore I need a validation rule like this:

```
return match ($this->input('step')) {
    '0' => [
        'form.company' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    ],
    default => [
        // Default rules if 'section' doesn't match any case.
    ],
};
```

The issue now is, that the response has a key named "form.company", but the response must be just "company", as I access the error like this, through the Inertia form: `form.errors.company`.

So somehow, within my axios call, I need to map the errors from the response with the form errors of the Inertia object:

```
catch((error) => {
    form.errors = error.response.data.errors;
});
```

But as I said, this does not work, because the key is not nested into:

```
"form" : {
    "company":
```

It is :

```
"form.company"
```

Now I ask myself whats the correct solution here? Is there another Inertia method that I should use or is axios the right thing to use here? When using axios, can I somehow return just "company" as the key and not `form.company`? Or do I need to parse the response on JS side, split the key `form.company` manually, and so on?

Does anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, the only soultion i was able to came up with was to use a library to validate forms on the front-end like https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/ to do stuff like (length check, regex, required fields, and not allowing user to progress to the next step if the currentone is not done yet) then do back-end validation because to for the same rules + anything that can't check on the front-end like username existence.

Comment: I did solve it, with just sending the form with a form.post to a php backend controller and validate the input fields through a FormRequest. This works fine, I had another issue before .That was the reason why I was confused.